# Facebook app is Public, but gives error "App not setup" when logging in

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-permissions

I have an Android app using Facebook to login.

The app is already public:
[image]

When trying to login via Facebook, I get this exception:

```
com.facebook.FacebookAuthorizationException: App Not Setup: This app is still in development mode, and you don't have access to it. Switch to a registered test user or ask an app admin for permissions.
```

Since the test users are able to login perfectly fine, I'm assuming that my code if fine.

Comment: Are you asking for more permissions other than 
`public_profile,user_friends,email`

Comment: Yes, user_birthday and user_about_me, but those are approved for the app as well. Please see the screenshot.

Comment: I see, have you added a contact email as well? (IN most cases, the logged in fb user i.e. the app creator) . If yes, then check if the package names are correct for the android app in the settings. Those are pretty much the checks to make it work really.

Comment: Yes, added contact email and all other possible details. The important thing is that that app is marked public. See the FILLED GREEN dot beside the App Name.

Comment: @Slartibartfast did those checks...Also, test users are able to login and use the app.. so those details are definitely correct.

Comment: If the problem persists, file a bug at developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: I am having the same problem in ios. Were you able to solve this??

Comment: I created a new Facebook app. No resolution on the old app.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the app status says that the App is public, yet you see the error with the SDK login, create a new app and start over.

This is a bug on facebook's end.

Answer (score 19):

1. In Settings → Basic → Contact Email → give your or any email.
2. Make sure you have a valid Privacy Policy available.
3. In the App Review Tab change:

   > Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public?

   to `Yes`.

Answer (score 6):

I also encountered this issue because I used wrong app id and app secret. Please use valid app id and app secret.

Comment: I did check that all relevant details were correct.

Answer (score 5):

1. Go to your App Dashboard.
2. Click on App Review which is located in the left side of the menu and make your app public.
3. Click "Yes".

Answer (score 4):

Unlike Google, **Facebook api needs a valid ssl certificate**. So if your website isn't https then according to facebook you are still in development mode. Here is the link to their docs https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/security

**For development purposes you can use the roles option** (can be found on the leftside menu). In here you can enroll your self as a developer or tester to use all the live features.

Once you are done with the development you will have to get an ssl certificate. You can also use a free service like https://letsencrypt.org to get a valid certificate, facebook requires your certificate to be **sha256WithRSAEncryption**, i personally haven't used letsencrypt with facebook yet but they are one of their sponsors to i guess it should meet their criteria of a decent certificate.