# App not setup: This app is still in development mode

Tags: android, ios, facebook, facebook-login

I have followed the instructions here:

[The developers of this app have not set up this app properly for Facebook Login?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21329250/the-developers-of-this-app-have-not-set-up-this-app-properly-for-facebook-login/26135600#26135600)

Made my app public and the circle is green so the app is public.

But when I try to login, I go to the Facebook app, it asks me to login which I do and then I get this message:

App Not Setup: This app is still in development mode, and you don't have access to it. Switch to a registered test user or ask an app admin for permissions.

BTW: I am the admin

Any help is much appreciated. I am using SeattleClouds and this happens on both iOS and Android.

Comment: Have you double-checked that the App ID in your Xcode project is the correct one and also checked your platform settings for your Facebook app (to be found at https://developers.facebook.com/apps/{APP_ID}/settings/)?

Comment: Did you find a solution for your problem?

Comment: Have you check this link ? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-users

Comment: @ArpitPatel , are you saying there needs to be a test-user?

Answer (score 284, accepted):

**STEP 1**:

In Settings -> Basic -> Contact Email. (Give your/any email)

**STEP 2**:
in 'App Review' Tab : change

*Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the    general public?* **Yes**

Comment: Great! But not working to test app. In test app we don't have the `Status and Review` tab.

Comment: why would you make a test app . you can do your all your testing on live app.

Comment: @captain_a because if you have a staging system with test and preview servers, you need test apps because you do not want mixup live app and test servers with new features.

Comment: And this is not a solution for Sarayee's problem. You do not want test apps live. It's most likely a test app of a live app. I do not know why so many ppl voted this up?

Comment: The tab has been renamed to "App Review".

Comment: What is if some one don't want to make app live yet want to distribute and test the app internally?

Comment: How come an admin can't test their own app and we are getting this error? WTH Facebook?

Comment: FB and other tech giants have gone too complex in developing such apps and options , and have forgot about the simplicity of usage by users. also we cant find any to the point help on the internet regarding these issues.

Comment: @captain_a It is also asking for the `privacy policy`, though I don't have any. Without adding privacy policy, it doesn't seem to work. :(

Comment: @captain_a Now I am not able to see this "Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public?" under the "App Review" tab  in the developer.facebook.com so can you please guide me

Comment: Not working. Still receive the same message in live state. Cheers ..

Answer (score 18):

This is an answer I haven't seen much around (this it was in a comment somewhere) although yes taking the app off development mode will work this can be bad for security or really annoying if the app isn't ready yet but you need to submit the app for review on account of needing access to special permissions (e.g. `user_birthday`).

What I did instead to fix the error was go to `https://developers.facebook.com/sa/apps/{appId}/roles/` or from the app dashboard click roles on the left side

Then add the user account(s) to either developer or tester. Developers will need to be verified by mobile and will get access to the app to make changes but a tester will only need to be verified by email (not sure if even this is necessary but it probably is) and will only be able to use the API instead of make changes to settings.

If the app is ready for the public, obviously just take the app off development mode.

Answer (score 10):

> Issue Log: **App Not Setup. This app is still in development mode. and you dont have access to it. register test user or ask an app admin for permission**

1. The app are not in Live Mode
2. You are not listed as admin or a tester in 
   https://developers.facebook.com/app/yourapp
3. Your App Hashkey are not set. if Facebook app cant be on Live Mode you need a hashkey to test it. because the app are not yet Live. Facebook wont allow an access.

**HOW TO CHANGE TO LIVE MODE**
 1. go to : https://developers.facebook.com
 2. select your app on "**My Apps**" List
 3. toggle the switch from OFF to ON

[image][image]

**HOW TO ADD AS TEST OR ADMIN**
 1. go to : https://developers.facebook.com
 2. select your app on "**My Apps**" List
 3. go to : Roles > Roles > Press Add for example administrator[image]
 4. Search your new admin/tester Facebook account.
[image]
 5. admin must enter facebook password to confirm.then submit
[image]

**the new admin must go to developer.facebook page and accept the request**
 6. go to : https://developers.facebook.com
 
 7. Profile > Requests > Confirm
 [image]
 [image: List item]
 8. **Congratulation** you have been assign as new Admin

**HOW TO GET AND SET HASHKEY FOR DEVELOPMENT**
as Refer to Facebook Login Documentation
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/#create_hash

The most preferable solution by me is by code ( **Troubleshooting Sample Apps** )

it will print out the hash key. you can update it on

https://developers.facebook.com/apps/yourFacebookappID/settings/basic/ 
on **Android > Key Hashes** section

**a step by step process on how to get the hashKey.**

1. Firstly Add the code to any oncreate method
   [image]
2. Run The app and Search the KeyHash at Logcat
   [image]

**step by step process on how Update on Facebook Developer.**

3. Open Facebook Developer Page. You need access as to update the Facebook Developer page.
   https://developers.facebook.com
4. Follow the step as follow.[image]

Answer (score 7):

**2021 UPDATE**

I have done successfully Login with Facebook by doing below things. Now it is working fine.

As per described by George Mano

Visit [Facebook Apps Page](https://developers.facebook.com/apps/) and select your application.

Go to **Settings -> Basic**.

Add a **1 Contact Email**, **2 Privacy Policy URL**, **3 User Data Deletion** and choose **4 Category** and Last **5. Live** your application

The Privacy Policy URL should be a webpage where you have hosted the terms and conditions of your application and data used.

The General Data Protection Regulation (GDPR) requires developers to provide a way for people to request that their data be deleted. To be compliant with these requirements, you must provide either a data deletion request callback or instructions to inform people how to delete their data from your app or website

Toggle the button in the top of the screen, as seen below, in order to **switch from Development to Live**.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and it took me around one hour to figure out where i went wrong only to note that i had used a wrong app id....just go to your code and used a correct id here

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId      : '1740077446229063',//your app id
        cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access
        // the session
        xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
        version    : 'v2.5' // use graph api version 2.5
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

**captain_a** is right that your app needs to be public with a developer email address. But if you are still getting the error then make sure that your website is using an **SSL certificate**.

**For more detailed information and workarounds** please checkout my answer at [Facebook app is Public, but gives error "App not setup" when logging in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29817602/facebook-app-is-public-but-gives-error-app-not-setup-when-logging-in/37892527#37892527)

Answer (score 3):

2020 UPDATE

Visit https://developers.facebook.com/apps/ and select your application.

Go to Settings -> Basic. Add a **Contact Email** and a **Privacy Policy URL**. The Privacy Policy URL should be a webpage where you have hosted the terms and conditions of your application and data used.

Toggle the button in the top of the screen, as seen below, in order to switch from **Development** to **Live**.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I did what is written in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30821009/10908886) answer and still had the same problem, then I downloaded the facebook app, logged into my facebook admin account from my phone. TADAA! it worked.

Comment: For anyone who is wondering what @Muhammed Aydogan meant by this, simply login to your tester account in the Facebook mobile app in the physical device you are testing your app in. In my case I was using the `Expo Go` app. It would be great if Facebook told us about it, or perhaps I have missed it out.

Comment: I've been plagued by this problem for hours, but I lacked this perspective. The problem has been resolved. Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

When app is release some time that case
[https://developers.facebook.com/apps/{$appid}/alerts/](https://developers.facebook.com/apps/%7B$appid%7D/alerts/)
"Your app has been placed into development mode due to an invalid Privacy Policy."
can change you app from release mode to development mode 
so check the Privacy Policy

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings->Basic, on top you will find a Switch button which will say App is in development mode.

[image]

Click on in development switch button, it will ask you to make app live, and after providing all necessary things, it will become live.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Facebook and Instagram apis were perfectly working fine but they suddenly stopped working due to invalid privacy policy statement. Facebook deactivated api access.

[image]

[image]