# Facebook App Not Setup:

Tags: android, facebook, cordova, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to implement facebook login with a test for a cordova app with this plugin 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-facebook4

The plugin works fine and opens facebook app but i get the following message.

**App Not Setup: this app is still in development mode, and you donot have access to it.**

I am using the same account throught which i created the app and still am getting this.

I have set the app **review**>**status**>**make app** live to on

I believe it is an graph setting issue Kindly tell me what is to be done here.

Comment: file a bug if you set your app live in the settings and still get the error: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/

Comment: check this out... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30085246/app-not-setup-this-app-is-still-in-development-mode/33428778#33428778