# Facebook Intrgation issue in iOS(App not set: app is still in devlopment mode)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, facebook-ios-sdk

[image]

I follow this link to resolve this issue but i have already did all things :-

[App not setup: This app is still in development mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30085246/app-not-setup-this-app-is-still-in-development-mode)

Also i am adding one more image for privacy issue on developer account. How can i resolve this.

[image]

Comment: well, add a privacy policy?

Comment: Need to add privacy policy into FB revice.

Comment: How can i add Privacy Policy URL ?? There is a option but how can i add url for privacy...it was just leaning purpose.

Comment: Also i tried to set one fake url and uninstall and install my app but i got same issue i.e.  app not set up: this app is still in development mode, and you do not have access to it.switch to a registered test user or ask an app admin for permission.

Answer (score 0):

Oh. I add wrong app id on plist.