# Social media integration error?

Tags: ios

I have integrated social media in my app, It was working properly but now Im having issues on Facebook, I recieved an error message `App not setup:this app is still in development mode`

Any Ideas what may have caused this error?

Comment: App Not Setup: This app is still in development mode, and you don't have access to it. Switch to a registered test user or ask an app admin for permissions

Answer (score 0):

Try this to make it public :

- Go to your Facebook app's dashboard at
  https://developers.facebook.com/apps/
- Select the "Status and Review" tab
- Set the toggle to "Yes"

Comment: Already tried but its not working

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30085246/app-not-setup-this-app-is-still-in-development-mode

Comment: Currently I m checking this link

Comment: My FacebookAppID was change but now i set again,its working fine Thank you