# Cannot log in with facebook - application still in development mode although IT IS NOT

Tags: android, ios, facebook, mobile, facebook-login

It is not typical.
Firstly we followed Facebook guide to setup fb login for both iOS and Android apps, even established app center on facebook dev. account and followed this article: [App not setup: This app is still in development mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30085246/app-not-setup-this-app-is-still-in-development-mode)

However, we still struggling with the very same issue: APP is not setup and still in development mode if it iOS app and this app has no hashes configured if it is Android app.

We created a brand new account fb. dev. account and established their fb login, changed needed information in the code and still result is the same.

Comment: i remove the js sdk because it is not related to your question. about your question: so what did you try? you should add some screenshots of your app settings.

Comment: Did you try to change the status of your app to "public" in the facebook developer portal?