# How to use Facebook test app to do Facebook Login - Web JavaScript

Tags: javascript, facebook-login, facebook-apps

This is my first time to write JavaScript.... I am using JSBin as the IDE. And I am trying to use JavaScript to allow users login and get their public data in Facebook Graph API.

I created a Facebook Web App, and then created a Test App for this App. None of these 2 Apps work. For each of these Apps, I have created a test user like this:

[image]

**Below Are How I Failed....**

**First Try:**
I have checked this [Facebook Login Doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web), changed the app id to my own app id, and version changed to 2.6 as my app settings. But, the problem is, on JSBin, nothing show up.....

**Second Try:**
Then I found [an online example](http://hayageek.com/facebook-javascript-sdk/), and I modified the code to make it like this

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({
appId      : '1814637902090044',
cookie     : true,  
xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
version    : 'v2.6' // use graph api version 2.6
});

FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) 
{
 if (response.status === 'connected') 
{
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML +=  "<br>Connected to Facebook";
}    
else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') 
{
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML +=  "<br>Failed to Connect";
} else 
{
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML +=  "<br>Logged Out";
}
}); 

};

function Login()
{
    FB.login(function(response) {
       if (response.authResponse) 
       {
            getUserInfo();
        } else 
        {
         console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
        }
     },{scope: 'email'});
}

  function getUserInfo() {
    FB.api('/100012237662406', function(response) {
    var str = "<b>Email:</b> "+response.email+"<br>";
    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML=str;

});
}


 // Load the SDK asynchronously
 (function(d){
 var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
 if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
 js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
 js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
 ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
 }(document));

 </script>
 <div align="center">
 <h2>Facebook OAuth Javascript Demo</h2>

  <div id="status">
Click on Below Image to start the demo: <br/>
 <img src="http://hayageek.com/examples/oauth/facebook/oauth- javascript/LoginWithFacebook.png" style="cursor:pointer;"   onclick="Login()"/>
 </div><div id="message">Logs:<br/>
  </div></div>
</body>
```

As you can see, I am using the app id of my Test App, the user is my test user id, but when I click the button, always get this error
[image]

**Third Try:**
Since above error shows "app in development mode....", I have checked these 2 solutions: [Solution 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30085246/app-not-setup-this-app-is-still-in-development-mode), [Solution 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29817602/facebook-app-is-public-but-gives-error-app-not-setup-when-logging-in). But I really cannot find those choices in `App Review` and I cannot find `Status & Review`. When it comes to Test App, it even has no `App Review`. Then I tried to public my App like this
[image]

But then I got the error:
[image]

Here are the url settings:
[image]

[image]

For that Redirect URL, I have also tried `http://localhost/oauthcallback.html`, but didn't work either. I don't have any real url can be used for redirect....

**I think**, if Test App without `App Review` can be used to test Facebook Login, it may not be the settings in `App Review` problems. 
Do you know how to solve this problem, so that my Javascript will allow user login and send me their public data in Graph API?